# How to parse message in view in backbone js

Tags: javascript, php, json, backbone.js

Here is  all my code. Whenever I fetch collection it shows blank in console.log.But I got data in response. So its throws undefined error of variable of templates file messages.  My App.js.

```
/*global define*/
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'collections/messageCollection',
    'views/message',
    'text!templates/main.html',
    'models/agentModel',
    'models/messageModel',
    'common'
], function ($, _, Backbone, Messagecollection, Message, mainTemplate, Agent,MessageModel,Common) {
    'use strict';

    var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#chatview',
        template: _.template(mainTemplate),
        events: {
            'click #new-message':'sendMessage',
        },
        initialize: function () {
            this.render();

        },
        render: function () {
            this.$el.html(this.template);
            this.subrender();

        },
        subrender:function(){
            this.$message = this.$('#messages');
            this.$header = this.$('#chat-head');
            var list = new Messagecollection();
            var message = new Message({ collection: list});
            this.$message.append(message);
        },
        sendMessage : function(){
            // var list = new Messagecollection();
            // var inputField = $('#message-to-send');
            // list.create({message: inputField.val()});
            // inputField.val('');

        },

    });
    return AppView;

});
```

My Message.js

```
/*global define*/
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'collections/messageCollection',
    'text!templates/message.html',
    'models/messageModel',
    'common'
],function ($, _, Backbone,MessageCollection ,messageTemplate, Messagemodel,Common) {
    'use strict';
    var MessageView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el : '#messages',
        template: _.template(messageTemplate),
        initialize: function(){
            this.render();
            return this;
        },
        render: function(){
            var Mess = new MessageCollection();
            this.$el.html(this.template(Mess.fetch()));
        },

    });
    return MessageView;

});
```

My Model

```
/*global define*/
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'common'
], function (_, Backbone,common) {
    Backbone.emulateHTTP = true;
    var MessageModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            id:'',
            message:'sdsd message',
            name: 'name',
            me:true,
            time:'10:00',
        },
        initialize: function () {
           console.log('message model loaded successfully');
        },
        url: function(){
            return common.root_url +"/api/messages/messageall";
        },

    });
    return MessageModel;
});
```

And Final my Message Collection

```
/*global define */
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/messageModel',
    'common'
], function (_, Backbone,MessageModel,common) {
    'use strict';
    var MessageCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: MessageModel,
        url: function(){
            return common.root_url +"/api/messages/messageall";
        },
        initialize: function(models, options) {
            options = options || {};
            this.url = options.url || common.root_url +"/api/messages/messageall";
        },
    });
    return MessageCollection;
});
```

My Template file of message view.

```
<li class="clearfix">
    <div class="message-data align-right">
        <span class="message-data-time"><%- time %></span> &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <span class="message-data-name"><%- name %></span> <i class="fa fa-circle me"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="message other-message float-right">
        <%- message %>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Please paste the error message you've got.

Comment: Undefined variable time.

Comment: Can you paste the response json received from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in collection initialize function you are using the option parameter you need to extend the model default values with the option values inside the model initialize function.

```
initialize: function () {
   this.options = _.extend({}, this.defaults, this.options);
},
```

> If you pass a `{collection: ...}` as the options, the model gains a
>   collection property that will be used to indicate which collection the
>   model belongs to, and is used to help compute the model's url. The
>   model.collection property is normally created automatically when you
>   first add a model to a collection.

```
/*global define*/
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'common'
], function (_, Backbone,common) {
    Backbone.emulateHTTP = true;
    var MessageModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            id:'',
            message:'sdsd message',
            name: 'name',
            me:true,
            time:'10:00',
        },
        initialize: function () {
           this.options = _.extend({}, this.defaults, this.options);
        },
        url: function(){
            return common.root_url +"/api/messages/messageall";
        },

    });
    return MessageModel;
});
```